# java https client is slow

Tags: java, https, client

I'm trying to access web API via java.

The API is on https server.

Unfortunately it works very slow.

When I access the API via my web browser,
it gives the response in 1 second.

When I access the API via java, 
it gives the response in 3 seconds.

What am I doing wrong? How can I get the response faster?

I noticed that the slow part is this line:
HttpResponse response1 = httpclient.execute(httpGet);

Here's my code:

```
static DefaultHttpClient httpclient ;

static {
    UsernamePasswordCredentials creds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("LOGIN", "PASSWORD");
     httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

     HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost("SERVER.org", 443, "https");

    httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
            new AuthScope(targetHost.getHostName(), targetHost.getPort()),
           creds);

    // Create AuthCache instance
    AuthCache authCache = new BasicAuthCache();
    // Generate BASIC scheme object and add it to the local
    // auth cache
    BasicScheme basicAuth = new BasicScheme();
    authCache.put(targetHost, basicAuth);

    // Add AuthCache to the execution context
    BasicHttpContext localcontext = new BasicHttpContext();
    localcontext.setAttribute(ClientContext.AUTH_CACHE, authCache);


  readXml("https://SERVER.org/PATH");
}



public static String readXml(String urlToRead){


    try {



        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(urlToRead);

            HttpResponse response1 = httpclient.execute(httpGet);



        try {
            System.out.println(response1.getStatusLine());
            HttpEntity entity1 = response1.getEntity();



            BufferedReader in;
            String inputLine;
            String result="";
            try {

                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entity1.getContent(),"UTF-8"));
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                  result+=inputLine+"\n";
                }
                in.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;


        } finally {
            httpGet.releaseConnection();
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

return null;    }

Comment: try adding in timing code (calls to System.currentTimeMillis()) to determine which lines are taking longer.  The code above will to authentication every time the entire thing is done, but in the browser, you might have a session that avoids authentication on every request.   Be nice to know which line takes all the time.

Comment: The "slow" part is: HttpResponse response1 = httpclient.execute(httpGet);

Answer (score 1):

I think it is slow in HTTPS handshake. There is no reason for new DefaultHttpClient in each request. You should use  PoolingClientConnectionManager to handle multi-http-client.

```
public Client(int maxConnectPerHost, int maxConnection, int connectTimeOut, int socketTimeOut,
        String cookiePolicy, boolean isAutoRetry, boolean redirect) {
    SSLContext sslcontext = null;
    try {
        sslcontext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sslcontext.init(null, new TrustManager[] {
            new TrustAnyTrustManager()
        }, new java.security.SecureRandom());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // throw something
    }
    // if a ssl certification is not correct, it will not throw any exceptions.
    Scheme https = new Scheme("https", 443, new SSLSocketFactory(sslcontext,
            SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER));
    Scheme http = new Scheme("http", 80, PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory());
    SchemeRegistry sr = new SchemeRegistry();
    sr.register(https);
    sr.register(http);

    connectionManager = new PoolingClientConnectionManager(sr, socketTimeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(maxConnectPerHost);
    connectionManager.setMaxTotal(maxConnection);
    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    params.setLongParameter(ClientPNames.CONN_MANAGER_TIMEOUT, connectTimeOut);
    params.setParameter(ClientPNames.COOKIE_POLICY, cookiePolicy);
    params.setBooleanParameter(ClientPNames.HANDLE_REDIRECTS, redirect);
    params.setBooleanParameter(ClientPNames.ALLOW_CIRCULAR_REDIRECTS, false);

    if (isAutoRetry) {
        client = new AutoRetryHttpClient(new DefaultHttpClient(connectionManager, params));
    } else {
        client = new DefaultHttpClient(connectionManager, params);
    }
}
```

and then use the client to send request. The client should be a singleton. Here is the doGet method. And the connection should not be released.

```
public HttpResponse doGet(String url, List<Header> headers)
            throws Exception {

    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
    if (headers != null) {
        Header[] array = new Header[headers.size()];
        headers.toArray(array);
        get.setHeaders(array);
    }

    try {
        HttpResponse resp = client.execute(get);
        return resp;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // throw something
    } 
}
```

Here is the request:

```
Client c = new Client(1024, 1024 * 1024, 10000, 10000, CookiePolicy.IGNORE_COOKIES, true, true);
HttpResponse r = null;
try {
    r = c.doGet("your url", null);
} finally{
    if (r != null) {
        EntityUtils.consumeQuietly(r.getEntity());
    }
}


// send request again. There is no https handshake in this time.
   try {
        r = c.doGet("your url", null);
    } finally{
        if (r != null) {
            EntityUtils.consumeQuietly(r.getEntity());
        }
    }
```

The handshake will be slow down your application. So you should not close/release connection in each request.